# Google Data Studio - Blended data Add non joined fields

Tags: looker-studio

I have one data set for campaigns from our marketing folks

```
CampaignID (PK)
CampaignName
CampaignDate
RecipientCount
```

I have another analytics data set from GA4

```
CampaignID (PK)
Opens
Clicks
Revenue
```

I want a report that has

```
CampaignID (PK)
CampaignName
CampaignDate
RecipientCount
Opens
Clicks
Revenue
```

I can join on the CampaignID and get Opens, Clicks and Revenue, but there doesn't seem to be a way to get other fields from the left table (CampaignName, CampaignDate, RecipientCount).

I was hoping I could add them as Metrics with aggregate Max(), but the only choice I have for non-numeric fields is Count and CountDistinct

If I add them as dimensions in the left table, need a matching dimension in the right table, so I made dummy fields with value NULL in the right table, but then the join fails. Seems the dimensions become join conditions.

Is there a way to get other non aggregate/join fields in the blended data set

Thanks

Mark

Answer (score 0):

A metric field can be aggregated including min and max.

For a date timestamp in a metric, following options are possible:

[image]